# Migrating Memcached client from Memcached-Java-Client to Xmemcached

Tags: java, memcached

I have an old memcached client implementation that is based of the danga client, but was slightly modified. I think this client is now called [Memcached-Java-Client](https://github.com/gwhalin/Memcached-Java-Client/).

The implementation I have at hand is old, unmaintained, and seem to be bogus.

I need to migrate the client to a newer client with the following constraints:

1. I need the new client hashing algorithm to be compatible with the old one. If this constraint is not met, we will have to make the site (at least partially) unavailable for a few hours.
2. Support various serialization methods, and allow extensibility for the serialization method.
3. Improved performance over my existing client.
4. Be compatible with [Moxi](http://code.google.com/p/moxi/)

The current implementation uses a consistent hashing algorithm which seemed to be compatible to the consistent hashing used by [Xmemcached](http://code.google.com/p/xmemcached/) except that I can't get a cache hit for keys stored by the old client and fetched with the Xmemcached client.

I debugged the code, and I get the same hashcode, but I think the servers ring is different, and thus the overall hashing method is different.

This is the code I used for initializing the xmemcached client:

```
  final MemcachedClientBuilder builder = new XMemcachedClientBuilder(AddrUtil.getAddresses("server:11211 server:11212 server:11213 server:11214"));
  builder.setCommandFactory(new BinaryCommandFactory());
  builder.setSessionLocator(new KetamaMemcachedSessionLocator());
  builder.setTranscoder(new WhalinTranscoder());
  memcachedClient = builder.build();
```

I am willing to also give [spymemcached](http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/) a try if I can't get xmemcached to work, but I prefer the later.

Edit: 
I tried spymemcached as well, and can't get it to be compatible with my current client.
Here's my spymemcached client initialization code:

```
final ConnectionFactoryBuilder builder = new ConnectionFactoryBuilder();
builder.setProtocol(Protocol.BINARY);
builder.setTranscoder(WhalinTranscoder());
builder.setHashAlg(HashAlgorithm.KETAMA_HASH);
builder.setLocatorType(Locator.CONSISTENT);
final MemcachedClient client = MemcachedClient(builder.build(), AddrUtil.getAddresses("server:11211 server:11212 server:11213 server:11214"));
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you less interested in spymemcached?  The author of moxi and the author of spymemcached (me) sit in the same room most days and we do a lot of work.  But more importantly, all of your requirements are goals of spymemcached and we've got both paid developers and open source contributors on it also working on memcached itself.

Comment: That's a good input @Dustin. I was not aware of this input. I saw some benchmark that was done by the author of xmemcached that showed better results + the fact that it's multithreaded led me to assume it will perform better under heavy load. I still haven't verified this assumption though, and still need to fulfill my other requirements. I also want to check which one has a more appealing API.

Comment: @Dustin, is spymemcached consistent hashing algorithm compatible with danga?

Comment: xmemcached has shown marginal speed improvements.  It's not slow, for sure.  The guy doing that started a lot later and has had a blank sheet to work with which is an enviable position.  I did a similar thing over Whalin's client and have had to provide compatibility with it, which led to some of my modularity.  You should be able to swap it in.  However, we're doing [a lot of work](http://dustin.github.com/2010/06/29/memcached-vbuckets.html) for next generation scaling models and other interesting stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like my old danga client is incompatible with the Xmemcached/Spymemcached clients due to a simple reason:
The danga client hashes the host:port strings while the later clients hash the InetSocketAddress which is effectively equals to host/IP:port.

Due to this fact I am unable to remain compatible when migrating to a newer client. Well, actually both Xmemcached, and Spymemcached clients are somewhat extensible and do allow some support in making this happen, but doing this will be too 'hacky' to my preferences.

What I decided to do is to migrate my code to use one of Xmemcached/Spymemcached according to benchmarks results. Both are compatible with moxi's hashing algorithm. 
I may eventually end up using a client side moxi only - depending on the overhead it will add. I like this option best since it makes the application configuration much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The way i understand you will have the same problem as in xmemcached with spymemcached. As i noted before here- http://bugs.membase.org/browse/MB-1484, the consistent hashing you are using now it a weighted consistent hashing as opposed to other 2, and that's why you are missing some of the keys.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. The reason for the incompatibility is the differences in the hashed object - host:port VS host/ip:port - see my answer above.